# What does error-"The truth value of a Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()" mean when plotting using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried subplotting using Pandas.

`df.plot(kind = 'box',subplots=True,use_index = False,layout = (6,6),title = df.columns,figsize=(12,8))`

which gave me the error.What does it mean?I tried checking other answers but I cant understand why would a plot return boolean values?And how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the parameter `title = df.columns`. This returns series-like object of all the columns in your dataframe. If you change this to something like: `title='My boxplot'` it should work.

Comment: df.columns returns an index (pandas.core.indexes.base.Index).  Convert this index to a list before passing to plotting title parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Robert's answer will result in a title above the entire figure (like a suptitle). His answer suggests that there is no way to have a title printed for each subplot.  This is incorrect.  Pandas pd.Dataframe.plot() [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html?highlight=plot#pandas.DataFrame.plot) say:

> **title**: *str or list*
>
> Title to use for the plot. If a string is passed, print the string
> at the top of the figure. If a list is passed and subplots is True,
> print each item in the list above the corresponding subplot.

Your problem is caused by passing an index (df.columns) to the plotting title parameter.  Assuming that you are trying to get column names printed as titles on each subplot, first convert df.columns to a list, and then pass that list to the 'title' parameter of your plotting call:

```
column_names = df.columns.tolist()
df.plot(kind = 'box',subplots=True, use_index = False, layout = (6,6), title = column_names, figsize=(12,8))
```